# MongoDB and Spark: Cannot cast STRING into a TimestampType

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I'm reading data in Spark from a MongoDB collection with the official MongoDB Spark Connector with the following code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.
            builder().
            appName("MongoDB to SQL").
            getOrCreate()

val df = MongoSpark.load(spark, readConfig)
df.count()
```

The readConfig is a standard read config for MongoDB, it works fine. The problem I have is with some date/time I'm getting from MongoDB as String, it fails to cast it to the Spark type TimestampValue:

```
 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: count at transfer.scala:159, took 3,138191 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver):
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a TimestampType (value: BsonString{value='2999.12.31 14:09:34'})
at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$.com$mongodb$spark$sql$MapFunctions$$convertToDataType(MapFunctions.scala:200)
at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:39)
at com.mongodb.spark.sql.MapFunctions$$anonfun$3.apply(MapFunctions.scala:37)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
```

From what I see when calling `df.printSchema()` before the `.count()` the attribute in question is listed as

```
|    |    |    |-- endDate: string (nullable = true)
```

In the MongoDB the endDate is also stored as String. Does Spark do an additional step here to detect a schema? And then it fails to cast it...? From looking at the source at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark/sql/MapFunctions.scala#L181 it only does simple mappings there, not complicated casts.

Used versions: Mongo-Scala-Driver 2.4.0, Mongo-Spark-Connector 2.3.0, Spark 2.3.1

Comment: I am facing the same issue but with String to integer cast error. Even proper sampling doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your issue, it seems that you need to convert date as string into timestamp (including time zone) using `unix_timestamp` and casting it as `TimestampType`

If you have a df with: df with [id: int, date: string]

```
val res = df.select($"id", $"date", unix_timestamp($"date", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp"), current_timestamp(), current_date())

res.printSchema

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- currenttimestamp(): timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- currentdate(): date (nullable = false)`
```

You can try to see this example : 
https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/timestamp-conversion.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder why it tries to cast to TimestampValue in the first place? I only do a `.count()` on the dataframe read from the MongoDB. Does it first do a schema inference from the MongoDB collection and then Spark or the MongoDB driver does an additional schema inference step where it somehow magically sees the String as TimestampValue (that's ok, but then it should do the cast and not fail IMO)?

Comment: It seems that in convertToDataType function, the pattern matching matches the case _, which in my opinion refers to the `endDate: string`

By converting it TimeStampType, it will create a new TimeStamp.
Correct me if I am wrong please

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but I think the schema displayed by printSchema seems to be different from the schema that the MongoDB connector "sees", as in line 195 it would match against String:
 `case (_, StringType) => bsonValueToString(element)`

and as we also see from the stacktrace it tries to cast to TimestampType (not to `StringType`). Guess there's something going on in Spark which I don't know yet, Anyway,thanks for your time/work on this q!

Comment: Ok, it’s interesting to know that. Does the conversion resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Mayby another field of your Schema cause this fault but not 'endDate'. No error info that you show say 'endDate' cause this error.

MongoDB Connector for Spark default use 1000 sample of your every field to build its schema, so if one field **contain different datatype such as string datatype and datetime datatype**, and MongoDB Connector for Spark can possiblely not sample the string data and take that filed as a datetime datatype. At least, when your use count method, connector will try to load data from mongodb to speifiy data type in spark dataframe, and cause this error: "Cannot cast STRING into a TimestampType"

**The Solution:**

**Add the sample data of MongoDB Connector for Spark to build a correct schema.** For example, in pyspark:

```
df = session.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option('sampleSize', 50000).load()
```

Comment: From the data I know that this error
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a TimestampType (value: BsonString{value='2999.12.31 14:09:34'})
points to the field "endDate". Anyway, I haven't worked with Spark for a while now as we're using other (and for our case probably better suited) technologies for our data integration platform. So I cannot tell what was the problem/solution in the end.

Comment: @Frank Thank you for your comment. Maybe the situation I encountered is not the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the data field that is  one entry has bson instead of a date its a bug on the mongo side there's a need for the schema to accommodate that